# Is there a technical name for a piece of music played as alternate style?

Tags: classical-music, styles

Is there a technical name for a piece of music played in an alternate style?

For example: in a documentary I saw a savant child play a sonata of Beethoven as if Mozart would have played it. Most of the notes were the same, but he added a lot of notes and the rhythm was influenced by Mozart.

Comment: Perhaps a pastiche? I have a friend whose speciality [& in fact, living] is just that, playing one piece in the style of another… though we never discussed what it may be called.

Comment: This all idea fascinates me, but i'm unable to find any videos linked with that technical name.

Comment: Well, a shameless plug for my friend Harry, his youtube channel - https://www.youtube.com/user/harrythepiano & [Oxford Online Dictionary definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pastiche)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a *technical* term per se, but you could describe it as being "in the style of" another composer. This is at least likely to find some results as a search term.

Charl's term "cover" is good too, though as he points out, it's not typically applied to Classical music.

Answer (score 0):

This would normally be termed a *parody* (if we're talking about classical music). Of course in popular music, it's simply a cover version!

Comment: parody:`an imitation of the style of a particular writer, artist, or genre with deliberate exaggeration **for comic effect**.`

Comment: It's not necessarily for comic effect, and particularly not so in music. Cf. **parody mass**: *A **parody mass** is a musical setting of the mass, typically from the 16th century, that uses multiple voices of another pre-existing piece of music, such as a fragment of a motet or a secular chanson, as part of its melodic material.* (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it a *reinterpretation*, because that's exactly what it is...reinterpreting the piece as the player thinks someone else would've done it.